# "At somebody's bidding" vs. "at somebody's behest"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, differences, phrase-meaning

Do the following two sentences have the same meaning? If not, what is the difference between them?

- This briefing session is held *at the Commander's **bidding***.
- This briefing session is held *at the Commander's **behest***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a commander issuing orders they both have the same meaning.

It would be possible to invent situations to force the reader to look at other dictionary definitions of behest (e.g. strong request rather than absolute command) but that is not productive in your context.